# How to change CAShapeLayer alpha/opacity value?

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I can't seem to change the opacity of my `CAShapeLayer` whatever I do. I tried setting the opacity:

```
    bottomProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    bottomProgressBar.opacity = 0.1
```

Didn't work. Then I tried this:

```
bottomProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.1).cgColor
```

In both cases the alpha value is 1.
Is there another way to do this ? Or am I setting them wrong ?

edit:

Here is my code:
This is a class inheriting from `UIView`:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configure()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    configure()
}

func configure() {
    bottomProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    bottomProgressBar.opacity = 0.1
    bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
    bottomProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
    bottomProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
    self.layer.addSublayer(bottomProgressBar)

    topProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    topProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
    topProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
    topProgressBar.strokeEnd = 1
    self.layer.addSublayer(topProgressBar)
}
```

edit 2:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: 0))

    bottomProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
    topProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
}
```

edit 3:

[image]

Comment: I've tested both of these solutions, both work for me.

Comment: Are you changing the correct one

Comment: I have a progress bar, with bottom and top views, my bottom view should have alpha set to 0.1 but is always 1. Both views have alpha set to 1. :/

Comment: @Brian: I updated the question with the code I have. And yes, it is called. Working correctly if I change the color of stroke. But not when changing alpha value.

Comment: Could it be a positional or animation issue? From the code it looks like `topProgressBar` is being laid directly on top.

Comment: @Brian: It's on top, but it starts with position 0. So first the visible view is bottomProgressBar. Like I said, everything seems to work correctly, because if I change the colour of the bottom view I can see it changed, but not when changing alpha value.

Answer (score 3):

I think what's happening is that you have no path defined for the shape to be rendered.

```
    func configure() {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))
        bottomProgressBar.frame = self.frame
        bottomProgressBar.bounds = self.bounds
        bottomProgressBar.path = path.cgPath
        bottomProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        bottomProgressBar.opacity = 0.1
//      no need for the following line as dimensions are already defined
//      bottomProgressBar.lineWidth = self.frame.height
//      bottomProgressBar.strokeStart = 0
//      bottomProgressBar.strokeEnd = 200
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomProgressBar)

        // path width divided by 2 for demo
        let topPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width/2, height: self.frame.height))
        topProgressBar.frame = self.frame
        topProgressBar.bounds = self.bounds
        topProgressBar.path = topPath.cgPath
        topProgressBar.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(topProgressBar)
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated my question with more code. I actually set the path in layoutSubviews(). Not sure how ok is it.

Comment: In that case you're original code is working. What's making you think it's not? Can you supply a screen shot? Edit: For example if you set `topProgressBar.strokeEnd = 0.5` you will see the underlining layer has transparency.

Comment: Done. As you can see the only thing that differs is bottom has 1 pt height, top has 2 pt height.

Comment: Ok, so you are right. I made a different project to test my class and yeah, the opacity works. It just doesn't work in my app for some reason.

Comment: I actually was able to reproduce the problem in the end. But I've no idea what causing it. The code above will work though. If it were me that's how I'd approach it.

Comment: Yeah, but its not working how I would want. It goes from 0 to 1 and then from 1 to 0 and than it completes, which seems strange. I just wanted to go from 0 to 1.

Comment: There are experts roaming around on [reddit.com/r/swift](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/) might be of more help to you.

Comment: Ohh I just fixed the issue. The view added in the storyboards had a white background. It should be clearColor. I just realised right now.

Answer (score 1):

Strange that it didn't work for you because `.opacity` is what changed the `layer's alpha` for me:

```
let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center,
                                          radius: (100,
                                          startAngle: -.pi/2,
                                          endAngle: 3 * .pi/2,
                                          clockwise: true)
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 6

shapeLayer.opacity = 0.3 // *** fades out the shape layer ***
```